# How to get the frequency counts of columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering how to get the frequency count of items of pandas dataframe like in the following question:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2,3,5,2],
                  'B': [10,10,10,300,400,500],
                  'C': ['p','p','q','q','q','q']})


print(df)
   A    B  C
0  1   10  p
1  1   10  p
2  2   10  q
3  3  300  q
4  5  400  q
5  2  500  q
```

## Required output

```
 A          B         C
(1,2)     (10,3)     ('p', 2)
(2,2)     (300,1)    ('q', 4)
(3,1)     (400,1)
(5,1)     (500,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct a list of [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) objects for each column, and reconstruct the dataframe:

```
from collections import Counter

c = [Counter(j for j in i).items() for i in df.values.T]
pd.DataFrame.from_records(c, index=df.columns).T

  A         B       C
0  (1, 2)   (10, 3)  (p, 2)
1  (2, 2)  (300, 1)  (q, 4)
2  (3, 1)  (400, 1)    None
3  (5, 1)  (500, 1)    None
```

---

In order to have sorted counts:

```
from operator import itemgetter
c = [sorted(
            Counter(j for j in i).items(), 
            key=itemgetter(1), 
            reverse=True) 
     for i in df.values.T]
pd.DataFrame.from_records(c, index=df.columns).T

     A         B       C
0  (1, 2)   (10, 3)  (q, 4)
1  (2, 2)  (300, 1)  (p, 2)
2  (3, 1)  (400, 1)    None
3  (5, 1)  (500, 1)    None
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your effort. This helps a lot.

Comment: Updated @MilkyWay001

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
s=df.stack().groupby(df.stack()).transform('count').unstack()
final=pd.concat([df,s])
final.groupby(final.index).agg(tuple)
```

---

```
       A         B       C
0  (1, 2)   (10, 3)  (p, 2)
1  (1, 2)   (10, 3)  (p, 2)
2  (2, 2)   (10, 3)  (q, 4)
3  (3, 1)  (300, 1)  (q, 4)
4  (5, 1)  (400, 1)  (q, 4)
5  (2, 2)  (500, 1)  (q, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
tmp = df.apply(lambda x: collections.Counter(x).most_common())
df_freq = pd.DataFrame(tmp,columns=['item_frequency_tuple'])

print(df_freq)
```

Gives:

```
                                 frequency
A         [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
B  [(10, 3), (300, 1), (400, 1), (500, 1)]
C                         [(q, 4), (p, 2)]
```

If you care for speed, never use apply:

```
%%timeit
tmp = df.apply(lambda x: collections.Counter(x).most_common())
df_freq = pd.DataFrame(tmp,columns=['item_frequency_tuple'])
#1.33 ms ± 14.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
vals = df.values.T
tmp = [ collections.Counter(vals[i]).most_common() for i in range(len(vals)) ]
df_freq = pd.DataFrame(np.array(tmp).T, columns=['item_frequency_tuple'])
# 430 µs ± 1.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```